# Is it possible to hide progress bar on Chromecast receiver side on live streams?

Tags: chromecast, caf-receiver-sdk

I would like to remove progress bar from CAF receiver while playing live stream

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/customize_ui

try setting the progress color to a transparent value

```
cast-media-player {
  --progress-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
```

also, use the inspector and check the DOM - this one should be

```
.player .controls-progress {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I have tried with with 
`let playerElement = document.getElementsByTagName("cast-media-player")[0];`
`playerElement.style.setProperty('--progress-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)');`
didn't help

Comment: it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but for the ones still facing the issue:

`cast-media-player` is a custom element, thus, including a shadow DOM you won't change directly.
All full-screen controls seem included in the sub custom element `tv-overlay`

So you can either access/change this element with:

```
document.querySelector("cast-media-player").shadowRoot.querySelector("tv-overlay").style.display = 'none';
```

You can potentially attach a new style sheet element to `cast-media-player` from your main page:

```
var style = document.createElement('style')
style.innerHTML = 'tv-overlay { display:none; }';
document.querySelector('cast-media-player').shadowRoot.appendChild(style)
```

Eventually, to debug your DOM/css receiver, you can access your receiver page with on Google Chrome though the URL `chrome://inspect/#devices`, and then click inspect on your device.

[image: Screenshot of the Chrome device tab]